# MDX : How to get dimension count for filtered members

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Country Count]
AS
Count(existing [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country])

MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassA AS
SUM(filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 3000))

MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassB AS
SUM(filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 1500))


MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassC AS
SUM(filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 0))

SET My_Custom_Set AS
{[Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassA, [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassB,[Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassC}

SELECT  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Measures].[Country Count]} ON COLUMNS,
My_Custom_Set ON ROWS
FROM 
[Adventure Works]
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

In the above query, How to get how many countries contribute class A, class B, class C, Here for any class the maximum country count 6 is displayed in measure 'Country Count' ?

Why Here **existing** is not providing the count of countries for **current class** ?

Comment: Thanks @Justin for formatting the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work, as you are working within the same hierarchy: `[Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassA` is a new member of this hierarchy, and the `FIlter` result is not contained in it, hence `EXISTING` does not work.

The following query works (note that the `count`s are on the base sets):

```
WITH 
SET ClassA AS
filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 3000)

SET ClassB AS
filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 1500)

SET ClassC AS
filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],[Measures].[Internet Order Count] > 0)

MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassA AS
SUM(ClassA)

MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassB AS
SUM(ClassB)

MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassC AS
SUM(ClassC)

MEMBER [Measures].[Country Count]
AS
CASE 
    WHEN [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember IS [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassA THEN
         ClassA.Count
    WHEN [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember IS [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassB THEN
         ClassB.Count
    WHEN [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember IS [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassC THEN
         ClassC.Count
    WHEN [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember IS [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All Customers] THEN
         [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].Count
    ELSE
         1
END


SET My_Custom_Set AS
{[Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassA, [Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassB,[Customer].[Customer Geography].ClassC}

SELECT  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Measures].[Country Count]} ON COLUMNS,
My_Custom_Set ON ROWS
FROM 
[Adventure Works]
```